# How to visualize the p-value from the $\chi^2$ test using RStudio?

Tags: r, data-visualization, chi-squared-test

I have conducted a chi-squared two-way test for independence, and I would like to visualize the p-value from the x2 test. What command to use in RStudio? Thanks! :)

This is my data:

```
    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  x
X-squared = 0.0013213, df = 1, p-value = 0.971

   19       21   
( 18.89) ( 21.11)
[6.2e-04] [5.5e-04]
< 0.0248> <-0.0235>

  143      160   
(143.11) (159.89)
[8.1e-05] [7.3e-05]
<-0.0090> < 0.0085>

key:
    observed
    (expected)
    [contribution to X-squared]
    <residual>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "visualize" a p-value? Would you visualize it differently if it were a p-valeu ffrom a different test?

Comment: What do you mean visualize the p-value?  It is just a single number.  Probably more interesting would be the visualize the entire table, and for this you might choose a mosaic plot: http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/mosaic.html.  Or you might just focus on one dimension and use simple bar plots.

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in seeing how your $\chi^2$ test statistic relates to your p-value, you could plot the $\chi^2$ density function and shade the area under the curve that is greater than the test statistic.

```r
    # Create a function for use with curves
    chisqPlot = function(x) dchisq(x, df=1)
    testStat = 0.0013213
    xmax = .2
    xmin = 0
    curve(chisqPlot, lwd = 3, from = xmin, to = xmax, 
        xlab = expression(chi^2), ylab = "density")

    # Create a shaded area under the curve
    x = seq(from = testStat, to = xmax, length.out = 1000) 
        # change to from = xmin, to = testStat if using left tail
    y = chisqPlot(x)
    x = c(testStat, x, xmax, testStat) # switch testStat to xmin, 
                             # xmax to testStat if left tail
    y = c(0, y, 0, 0)
    polygon(x,y, lty = 3, border = NULL, col = "#88888888")
```

[image: chi-square Density]

The grey shaded area is the p-value.

Comment: It would be a strange application indeed that focuses on this range of values of $\chi^2$!  The shaded area shown, which is around $0.3$, is far less than the actual p-value, which is around $0.97$.